# Change Bases of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

I have:

> T: $P_2(R)\to P_1(R)$
>
> $T(a + bx + cx^2) = (a - 3b + c) + (2a - 6b + 3c)x$

Need to find bases $\alpha' ,$  $\beta'$ such that $[T]_{\alpha'\beta'}$ is reduced echelon form
 of  $[T]_{\alpha\beta}$ ($\alpha, \beta$ - standart bases)

1. I found

   > $$[T]_{\alpha\beta} =
   >         \begin{matrix}
   >         1 & -3 & 1 \\
   >         2 & -6 & 3 \\
   >         \end{matrix}
   > $$
   >   $$[T]_{\alpha'\beta'} =       \begin{matrix}
   >         1 & -3 & 0 \\
   >         0 & 0 & 1 \\
   >         \end{matrix}
   > $$
2. Then I know that

> $[T]_{\alpha'\beta'} =[I]_{\beta'\beta} [T]_{\alpha\beta} [I]_{\alpha\alpha'}$

But I can't find none of change of basis matrices, without knowing any vectors in $\alpha'$ or $\beta'$

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance

Edit: corrected a mistake

Comment: According to the formula for $T$, $T(1)=1+2x$, which does not agree with the first column of $[T]_{\alpha \beta}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that row equivalence applied to the matrices in question amounts to \begin{equation} [T]_{\alpha' \beta'}=P [T]_{\alpha \beta} I_{3} \end{equation} where $P$ is an invertible matrix (representing the product of elementary matrices corresponding to the elementary row operations to obtain the RRE form). So you can find $P$ by augmenting $[T]_{\alpha \beta}$ by $I_2$ and then row reducing the augmented matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post.

Comment: But $[T]_{\alpha \beta}$ is $2\times 3$ so how can I get an invertible matrix out of it?

Comment: $P$ is the invertible matrix, and it is $2 \times 2$.

Comment: So you have to do the following: row reduce $[I_2 \;|\;[T]_{\alpha \beta}]$ to $[P \;|\;[T]_{\alpha' \beta'}]$. So basically what it comes down to, explicitly, $P=[I]_{\beta' \beta}$ and $I_3=I_{\alpha \alpha'}$, which also implies $\alpha=\alpha'$

Comment: Oh, I see now! thank you